# php including any href links included in xpath text echo

Tags: php, xpath, hyperlink

Trying to get good at php web scraping. Doing some tests and I've nailed scraping/echoing that information from one site to another, but I'm unable to also include the original links in the source code, which is what I'd ideally like to do. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this with what I've got thurs far? (I'm very new to php btw).

this is the php code:

```
// news
$doc = new DOMDocument;

// We don't want to bother with white spaces
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// Most HTML Developers are chimps and produce invalid markup...
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;

$doc->loadHTMLFile('https://www.usatoday.com/');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = "//ul[@class='hfwmm-list hfwmm-4uphp-list hfwmm-light-list']";

$entries = $xpath->query($query);
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
 echo trim($entry->textContent);  // use `trim` to eliminate spaces
}
```

that code is spitting out this: NBA Cavs win record-breaking Game 4 behind Irving's 40 Entertain This Watch: 'Black Panther' trailer unleashes a fearsome king News Police: London Bridge terrorists planned more bloodshed How Trump is highlighting divisions amo..........

Now what I'd really like to do, is actually have those as working links, which was what it was in the original code. this is what the source code for this information looked like:

```
<div class="partner-heroflip-ad partner-placement ui-flip-panel size-xxs"><a 
href="#" class="partner-close"></a></div></div><p class="hfwmm-tertiary-
list-title hfwmm-light-tertiary-list-title">TOP STORIES</p><ul class="hfwmm-
list hfwmm-4uphp-list hfwmm-light-list"
data-track-prefix="flex4uphphero"><li class="hfwmm-item hfwmm-secondary-item 
hfwmm-item-2 sports-theme-bg hfwmm-first-secondary-item hfwmm-4uphp-
secondary-item"
data-asset-position="1"
data-asset-id="102694848"
 ><a class="js-asset-link hfwmm-list-link hfwmm-light-list-link hfwmm-image-
link hfwmm-secondary-link
href="/story/sports/nba/2017/06/10/kyrie-irving-lebron-james-cavs-win-game-
4/102694848/"
data-track-display-type="thumb"
data-ht="flex4uphpherostack1"
data-asset-id="102694848"                 
><span class="hfwmm-image-gradient hfwmm-secondary-image-gradient"></span>
<span class="js-asset-section theme-bg-ssts-label hfwmm-ssts-label-top-left 
hfwmm-ssts-label-secondary sports-theme-bg">NBA</span><img 
src="https://www.gannett-cdn.com/-
mm-/cd17823b265aa373c83094fc75525710f645ec90/c=0-178-4072-
81338209183-USP-NBA-FINALS-GOLDEN-STATE-WARRIORS-AT-CLEVELAND-91573076.JPG"
 class="hfwmm-image hfwmm-secondary-image js-asset-image placeholder-hide"
  alt="Kyrie Irving reacts after making a basket against the"
  data-id="102695338"
  data-crop="16_9"
  width="239"
  height="135" /><span class="hfwmm-secondary-hed-wrap hfwmm-secondary-text-
hed-wrap"><span class="hfwmm-text-hed-icon js-asset-disposable"></span><span
  title="Cavs win record-breaking Game 4 behind Irving&#39;s 40"
  class="js-asset-headline hfwmm-list-hed hfwmm-secondary-hed placeholder-
hide">
      Cavs win record-breaking Game 4 behind Irving&#39;s 40
     hfwmm-item-3 life-theme-bg hfwmm-4uphp-secondary-item"
   data-asset-position="2"
```

For sanity, the href above is   href="/story/sports/nba/2017/06/10/kyrie-irving-lebron-james-cavs-win-game-
4/102694848/"

Any thoughts on how this might be accomplished in this test scenario, would be hugely helpful. Thank you very much. -wilson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to output the element as a string, your just extracting the text of the element (not the same thing with XML). The element may be `<a>some text</a>` the text is simply `some text`.

To output the tags, use...

```
$query = "//ul[@class='hfwmm-list hfwmm-4uphp-list hfwmm-light-list']//a";

$entries = $xpath->query($query);
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $newdoc = new DOMDocument();
    $cloned = $entry->cloneNode(TRUE);
    $newdoc->appendChild($newdoc->importNode($cloned,TRUE));
    echo $newdoc->saveHTML();
    //echo trim((string)$entry);  // use `trim` to eliminate spaces
}
```

Also note that I've added //a on the end of the XPath expression to limit the selection to links in the segment you where fetching.  This may or may not be what you want, but look at the results and check it out.

Edit:

To manipulate the href in the , then use something like...

```
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $oldHref = (string)$entry->getAttribute("href");
    $entry->setAttribute("href", "http://someserver.com".$oldHref);
    $newdoc = new DOMDocument();
    $cloned = $entry->cloneNode(TRUE);
    $newdoc->appendChild($newdoc->importNode($cloned,TRUE));
     echo $newdoc->saveHTML();
}
```

Comment: Hey Nigel, thanks so much for that! Super helpful! Shows those as links now. Two things that are not quite ideal though that I'm wondering if you know how to change. The links don't actually direct to the right reference, in fact they don't go anywhere really. Second thing is, actually some images display too now next to the links, which isn't ideal. But thanks again.

Comment: @Masteryogurt The tags include all sorts of extra crap, if you just want the href, then change the XPath to `$query = "//ul[@class='hfwmm-list hfwmm-4uphp-list hfwmm-light-list']//a/@href";` and your loop will use `echo trim($entry->value)."\n";`

Comment: Nigel, realized something very silly. The code you originally provided, the links do work. The issue is my own server isn't displaying the root reference of that website. In other words, the links is taking me to _____/story/12538. Which likewise appears as a broken link. Had my server been usatoday.com as the root, that link would work. Any idea how to make that link work if I have a different root server? A custom way of like injecting usatoday.com before it? Interesting situation.

Comment: @Masteryogurt I've added another bit of code in the answer which allows you to manipulate the href.

Comment: Nigel! I love it, works like a charm. You've been so helpful with this php code and solutions, really appreciate it. Teaching me to be a better php'er as well. Also, being as you seem to be exceptionally knowledgeable about php, I have a separate question thread regarding image scraping, if you have any time I would be curious your thoughts on it. Otherwise, thanks again! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44474709/fixing-php-image-scraper-code-to-be-more-flexible-in-different-situations