# fixing php image scraper code to be more flexible in different situations

Tags: php, image, xpath

I was able to construct some code that grabs an image from the below website where the image link will be random every time, and mirrors it on another site. While it's great that this works, I'm unable to copy this format onto any other site. I see that the image is being grabbed with a getElementbyId "file," but from the original source code there are many many refrences to "file," so I'm a bit stuck. very knew to php still.

What I'm trying to be able to do, is replicate the below result, but on any site with a particular image.

```
 <?php
$html = 
file_get_contents("http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:Random/File");
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$remoteImage = $dom->getElementById("file")->firstChild->attributes[0]-
>textContent;
header("Content-type: image/png");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($remoteImage));
echo file_get_contents($remoteImage);
?>
```

Trying to figure out how I could reproduce that on this site for ex https://pokemondb.net/pokedex/wartortle

where I'm trying to pull the wartortle.jpg

My initial idea if not knowing exactly what the image would hypothetically be named, since I want this to work during random conditions, is to identify the image with it's tag < div class="colset">

Alas, plugging in "colset" instead of "file" didn't do the trick though.

Any thoughts?? Thanks so much.-Wilson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XPath is always a lot more flexible (although probably slower than other solutions).  Using the previous example you could use the following to get the file name...

```
<?php
ob_start();
$doc = new DOMDocument;

$doc->loadHTMLFile('https://pokemondb.net/pokedex/wartortle');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = "//li[@id='svtabs_basic_8']//img/@src";
ob_end_clean();
header('content-type: image/jpeg');
$entries = $xpath->query($query);
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    readfile((string)$entry->value);
}
```

I've added the ob_start and ob_end_clean to remove the xml validation errors.

Comment: Hey Nigel. Really appreciate you giving this one some feedback as well. I see the logic of what you've put in above, and yes I'm able to get the link file name to appear. Do you know how to make the actual image appear however? That's what I was able to accomplish in the above code I used, and was my ultimate goal. Though this is a good start

Comment: Depends on how you want the image to appear, you could just include it in an img tag (which is how it is done in the original site).

Comment: Oh I see. I tried to reference it the way I had done previously like this <img src="test2.php" height"300" width="400">, but it's giving me a broken link. then opening up the actual php file I was referencing, to see if I Could figure out what was up, got this. Fatal error: Call to a member function loadHTMLFile() on a non-object in /home/wilsons888/public_html/test2.php on line 2. not sure if there's an answer in that message.

Comment: Ermmmm... think I missed the `$doc = new DOMDocument();` off the front... don't tell anyone else though :-/

Comment: Also - if you want it to put out the image, you can change the echo to `readfile((string)$entry->value);` (from what I've read anyway in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069112/can-i-echo-a-jpg-image-through-php-without-processing-it)

Comment: hm not sure how to make that work exactly, just replace the last line of your code with readfile((string)$entry->value);? Guessing not, probably need to integrate it with the echo line in some way. and in regards to the external reference, still not able to get the img to appear, still showing as broken. ill write out what the php now looks like, to make sure I'm not butchering something

Comment: <?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('https://pokemondb.net/pokedex/wartortle');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = "//li[@id='svtabs_basic_8']//img/@src";

$entries = $xpath->query($query);
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    echo "File=".(string)$entry->value;
}
?>

Comment: and this is the html ref <img src="test2.php" height"300" width="400">

Comment: Ah Nigel thank you sir! Excellent stuff, once again. So it seemed to be a xml validation issue, interesting. and good to know the solution for that. Unrelated, now that I know how to reference a php img in xml, do you know the best method of referencing a text output? such as xpath scrape text data. would it be < ?php include 'xpath1.php';?>  for ex